# Flutter/Dart : reading in text file is prefixed by weird characters

Tags: android, json, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm moving from Android Studio to flutter. In the Android Studio project , I write files in a JSON format using this code:

```
String json = gson.toJson(item);
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
  fos = context.openFileOutput("item"+ item.getUid(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  os.writeObject(json);
  os.close();
  fos.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

I now want to load in these files in Flutter SDK using this code

```
Future<List<Item>> loadAllItems() async {
  try{
    var items = <Item>[];
    var filesDir = Directory("/data/user/0/com.company.app/files");

    for(var f in filesDir.listSync()){
      if(f is File){
        f.readAsString(encoding: latin1).then((jsonstr) => {
          items.add(parse(jsonstr))
        });
      }
    }
    return items;
  } catch(e){
    log(e);
  }
  return [];
}
```

But the problem is that the string `jsonstr` is now prefixed by weird characters.
Here's how it is saved and loaded in at Android Studio

> {"property1":"value1", ...}

and this is how it's read in in Flutter SDK

> ¬í t${"property1":"value1", ... }

I also tried using utf8 encoding but this raises an exception

> Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8'

So how to get the normal JSON string without the weird symbols before it?

Comment: Aren't those 3 characters the prefix that tell `ObjectInputStream` the java type of the bytes that follow? They look like the stream magic bytes from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html. You will need to snip them off (they should always be the same - allowing for the fact that 2 bytes encode the string length) and then UTF-8 decode the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title says "reading in text file...", but of course you aren't reading in a *text* file - you are reading in a Java object serialization, as created by `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`. So now you need to read and interpret [that format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#10152).

As you've written a single string, the output will consist of the stream header, then a `string` identifier plus the length of the string, then the string.

Create a method to read the file and parse the header:

```
Future<String> readJavaObjectFile(File file) async {
  var bytes = await file.readAsBytes() as Uint8List;
  var data = bytes.buffer.asByteData();
  assert(data.getUint16(0) == 0xaced); // stream_magic
  assert(data.getUint16(2) == 5); // stream_version
  assert(bytes[4] == 0x74); // tc_string
  var length = data.getUint16(5); // length thereof
  return utf8.decode(bytes.sublist(7, 7 + length));
}
```

and call it from your loop:

```
Future<List<Item>> loadAllItems(Directory filesDir) async {
  var items = <Item>[];
  for (var f in await filesDir.list().where((e) => e is File).toList()) {
    items.add(parse(await readJavaObjectFile(f)));
  }
  return items;
}
```

or like this

```
Future<List<Item>> loadAllItems(Directory filesDir) async {
  var files = await filesDir.list().where((e) => e is File).toList();
  return await Future.wait(
      files.map<Future<Item>>((f) async => parse(await readJavaObjectFile(f))));
}
```

Note that there's a bug in your version. You only add members to `items` in the `then` which won't get executed until the future. It's simpler to get right with the `await` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you also need write files with utf8 encoding in your java code:

```java
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Then what's the default encoding? And since this is already too late (app is already deployed to thousands of users and their data needs to be kept), what could be a solution to this problem?

Comment: i did a quick search and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390457/what-character-encoding-does-objectoutputstream-s-writeobject-method-use @WouterVandenputte